# Flex Mobile log output in iOS

Tags: android, ios, apache-flex, flex-mobile

I'm trying to debug an issue on a Flex Mobile project.  Specifically, in order to debug this I need to be using a release build for iOS (it is the only way the problem appears).  I am having difficulty finding a way to view log messages on a release build.  Has anybody been able to successfully see log messages in the Organizer console?  If so, how did you accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be a release build, I can think of two options:

1. Using Google Analytics in the Flex mobile project and then log your errors to a "test" bucket so it doesn't get mixed up with your real reporting.
2. Save a txt file with log info, and then read it back in

Neither are great solutions, but I think it is the best you can do with a release build.